# How to Add OSM Layer to QGIS 2.X

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

**How can i add OSM layer in QGIS?**

The help says there is an [OSM plugin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS_OSM_Plugin) i can use. But i don't see it the list of plugins.
[image]

**Or maybe there is a WMS URL for OSM i can use?**

> QGIS version 1.7.0-Wroclaw on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Fetch Python Plugins

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670

Answer (score 34, accepted):

March 2015 update with QGIS 2.8.1 (Wien)

Web>Openlayers plugin

[image]

**For Raster images** [after fetching python plugins]
use the OpenLayers Plugin

[image]

**For Vector (editable layers)**
use the OpenStreetMap Plugin

use Download OSM Data option [OSM server limits large downloads] - zoom into an area of interest first there is some info when using the plugin that the area is ok to download - this will take a minute or so to process.

To edit save as shapefile (load this into QGIS) and toggle editing

[image]

Comment: This was created on a Windows 7 (SP1) 64-bit PC with 8GB RAM. Intel i5 3.2Ghz

Comment: @Rostranimin updated for QGIS 2.8.1

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question/answer but it pops out in the Google search and it is worthwhile adding new updates as in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217670/84356) answer. I would comment but I don't have enough reputation.
There is no need for an extra plugin, you can use the **XYZ Tile Server**.

[image]

The URL for OpenStreetMap is:

```
http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

**Update for QGIS3**
QGIS3 comes with a direct link to OpenStreetMap under **Tile Server (XYZ)**, just double-click on it:

[image]

Comment: thanks, always true with my QGis 2.18.17 under Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this Q/A link below.

[How to get OpenStreetMap as a raster layer in QGIS](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/400/how-to-get-openstreetmap-as-a-raster-layer-in-qgis)