# Define area of study in Google Earth before Import in Qgis

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I wish implement a GIS solution to manage a water and wastewater network.
In my project I have any map for use it like background.
So, I think the only solution for having a layer background, is to define it from Google Earth.
I must define the scope of study or area of study in Google Earth, after I import it in Qgis.

Can someone help me in this step, and give me advice ?

Also, if someone has any documentation or tutorial, it can help me.

Answer (score 1):

As GM says, you must enable the Openlayers Plugin by using the plugin manager.

Your challenge will be to print the "map" which you have created with Google Earth imagery as a background and your network laid over it. 
Google imagery has license limitations in it's use. 
QGIS has a Print Composer where you arrange the map and export it to a pdf or other file type. Print Composer works OK with Google Earth imagery if you leave the main map canvas set to the Mercator CRS.

Answer (score 1):

On qgis go to plugins menu, from there select **Fetch Python Plugins**. Let it download the list. In the search box enter **Openlayers Plugin**, and install the one called **Openlayers Plugin**. I think the latest version is 0.9 something.

After you've installed it go to project properties and select the appropiate CRS (for bing and google maps select google mercator EPSG:900913)

Next got to plugin menu in the Menu line, select Openlayers Plugin and select either google or bings aerial - just a matter of preferment.

You can select openstreetmaps as well but im not sure if they use the same CRS.

Always remember that those wms are just a background pictures, what will help you later is to **select the appropriate CRS**

Also take a look here :
[Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/how-to-add-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

as others already told you: select plugins-->fetch python  plugins. now abort fetching and click the repositories-tab and add the sourcepole repositorium (http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml)
[image]

then click the plugins-tab and add openlayers plugin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a polygon on Google Earth and save it as .kml
2. Open QGIS. Use ( Add vector layer ) on the left and choose the kml file.
   [image]
3. Vector > openStreetMap > Download Data [image]
4. Choose the kml file and don't forget to name the output file. Press OK.[image]
5. Now again, use ( Add Vector Layer ) on the left and choose the output file you just saved ( it is an osm file )[image]
6. Choose which layer you want from the polygon's contents.
   I personally used this for the street map ( lines )[image]

You'll notice that it's slightly out of bounds. You can use the clipping function to fit it within the study area.

[image]