# How to improve OSM layer resolution in OpenLayers plugin while exporting?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm having trouble with the OpenLayers Plugin exporting a map to a png or pdf file:

The output resolution of the exported osm-layer is very, very poor. Zooming to 100% in the png file shows big pixels. The rest of the map - so the output from shapes and fonts - is in the usual high resolution e.g. 300 or 600 dpi.

Is there any way to improve the osm-background-resolution?

Comment: Related to [OpenLayers low resolution and/or shifts in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/openlayers-low-resolution-and-or-shifts-in-qgis-print-composer?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short Answer: No, not yet.

OSM tiles come as bitmaps. You might use tiles of a higher zoom level, but lables will appear smaller, and details become more tiny.

A solution might be to request a SVG export from the original openstreetmap.org website, georeference it and insert it into your Qgis canvas.

Or render your own tiles, with an inceased labelling size.

This page gives some hints:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper

But this is not part of the Openlayers plugin.

Comment: Ok, thank you than I'll wait :)

Georeferncing it myself is a terrible thing for me. I'm not very good at it and it never fits perfectly in the end... The only thing I would do was if it would be possible to export already geo-referenced Geo-Tiff-Files from OSM... But I don't know if that is possible or if there is a service available that can do it.

Comment: The only solution I know is a little Windows program named taho.exe: http://www.dimitri-junker.de/eng/html/openstreetmap.html. It can stitch tiles together and add a worldfile for EPSG:3395.

Comment: have you tried to export the osm via maperitive, which of course can create a word-file to? url: http://maperitive.net/ or use the openstreetmap plugin (vers. 0.5 at the moment) the openstreetmap plugin gives you a vector layer versu to the openlayersplugin

Answer (score 3):

I kind of solved this problem!
First as it was explained here ([OpenLayers low resolution and/or shifts in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/openlayers-low-resolution-and-or-shifts-in-qgis-print-composer?rq=1)) use **Quick Map Services**!
Then select **50pp of dpi** (Resolution) and in Composition **select A5 size page** (148mm- 210mm). It doesn't lose Resolution as it does when it is A4 page or larger.And when exporting to PDF, the size of street names and the detail of streets gets bigger

[image]

Hope it can help!