# Label size changes when exporting or printing WMTS layers

Tags: qgis, export, printing, print-composer, wmts

I am using QGIS2.4.0 on a Windows computer. When I export a map containing OSM landscape, the labels in the output map are smaller then in the view in the composer. (even if the view in the composer is at zoom 100%)

This is not the only difference, here an example (click to magnify images):

#### The view in the composer

[image: view in the composer]

#### The exported file

[image: exported file]

You can see that the labels are now impossible to read.

I want to be able to print and export the view as I see it in the composer.

I tried the solutions for the question [How to improve OSM layer resolution in OpenLayers plugin while exporting?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42305/how-to-improve-osm-layer-resolution-in-openlayers-plugin-while-exporting) but that didn't help.

So the problem is not the openlayers plugin.

Comment: The OpenLayers plugin has not been designed for use with maps printed using the composer, and you'll run into many bugs like this. You'll need to contact the plugin author and see if he has any plans to add support for this feature in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I am having the same problems whith maps I added without using the Open Layers plugin, when I tried the solutions from http://www.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92315/how-to-increase-label-size-of-openlayers-plugin-basemap-layers and http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QG. That's why I thought the plugin was not the problem.

Comment: To show this I uninstalled the openlayerplugin and used this method to add the layer :
http://3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS

The labels in the export are still too small, much smaller than in the composer.
http://oi62.tinypic.com/k4uxhi.jpg