# QGIS image export changes the map center and scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've been trying to export a few map layers using QGIS print composer. First, I loaded the layers and opened the composer using `Project -> New Print Composer`:

[image]

Gave it a proper name:
[image]

Added a new map:
[image]

Exported as image:
[image]

However, the outcome is shifted a few dozens of kilometers westwards:
[image]

This specific west shift is inconsistent; sometimes I experience a smaller shift or a shift in another direction. Moreover, the scale often changes too - which makes map exporting impossble.

I'm using the newest QGIS version:
[image]

**Any idea how to export the image properly? I'm currently using screenshots, which are a poor solution.**

Comment: Is your project using 'on the fly' projection? And have you set the view projection to be something _other_ than the Google false mercator (EPSG: 3857)?

Comment: hi.for some project i use the ITM (Israel Transverse Mercator) and get the same result.

Comment: Try setting the projection to 3857 before you export and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: sory 3857? i don't now whoet it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems using the 64-bit Qgis; I have NOT had this problem using the 32-bit version of qgis.  My workaround was to switch to the 32 bit version.

Comment: thnks. cun i swich withe wundowes 8 withe system tip 64-bit to qgis 32-bit version?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the bug report for this issue: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827#change-55576

These problems have been around forever, see [Why do OpenLayers plugin layers appear shifted in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/why-do-openlayers-layers-appear-shifted-in-map-composer)

It's known. The only thing that seems missing are resources to actually fix it.