# In QGis, why do parts of the OpenLayers layer export in a different scale and position?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a problem printing with google satellite maps in QGIS. In the composer it's all right, but in the pdf file some portions of the image are in a different scale and in a different position.

An image can talk more then 1000 words…

[image]

EDIT: My problem isn't misalignment, and the problem occurs independently from size or position. It's something like the bug of which talk about in [this page](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4223). How can you watch in the image that I inserted before, the correct image is the portion at the center, while the rest is in a scale smaller (the street above can't be bigger than the houses).

Comment: Please try to find thread titles which describe the problem rather than "problem with xy", "xy does not work", ...

Comment: There are many issues when trying to use the Openlayers layer in a print composer. As far as I'm concerned at the moment (June 2015) the solution is NOT to use the openlayers layer in a print composer at any time.

Comment: @underdark As I wrote months ago, is not a problem of shifted layers, so this question is not a duplicate, for sure not of [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/why-do-openlayers-layers-appear-shifted-in-map-composer). As I wrote under the image, and also as the image shows, the problem is that some tiles are showed in a different scale.

Comment: I agree with @Rostranimin you shouldn't use Openlayers when printing. There are scale issues due to differing DPI between the printed image and the image viewed in the print composer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it may be best to use an alternative base layer within OpenLayers plugin, such as Bing.

If you have already tried this and the fault still exists, then may I suggest you take a screenshot of your desired basemap (I assume it is displaying correctly within standard QGIS data view?), crop it and save it as a .tif or .jpeg and then load it back in to QGIS and georeference it using "Georeferencer" which can be found under the raster tab. If it is not there then go to Plugin Manager and make sure Georeferencer is ticked.

Once you have correctly georeferenced your basemap you will then be able to place other layers on top and properly export as pdf.

Hope this helps.