# Misplaced Google Maps with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, google-maps, coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I was using Google Maps with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS with my vector layer with projection EPSG:4326 with google map projection EPSG:3857 and "on the fly" transformation enabled.

It was matching all the vector layer with Google Maps but now it's not working.

How can I reproject Google Maps so that it matches with my vector layer as before?

Comment: Project CRS should be set to EPSG:3857, not 3785.

Comment: sorry by mistake i typed ..it was in EPSG:3857 only

Comment: That should work, unless you zoom in too far. Does Openstreetmap or bing background via the plugin fit?

Comment: Yes Opensteetmap and others maps fit....bt google street map...or any other google plugin is not fitting ...... :(

Comment: What scale is reported by QGIS? See also this bug ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822

Comment: previously it was working at all scale but now its not fitting at any scale..

Comment: I have the same problem only with google layers, not openstreetmaps or bing layers

Comment: I have the same problem in QGIS 2.6 and OpenLayers plugin, so upvoted question.

Comment: I cannot plus 1, however, I used Unibasil's solution and it worked.
Thank you.

Comment: unibasil solution works

Comment: @user2853298, if my answer solves your problem (and you think it deserves), you can check it as the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to find a solution, I've changed `OpenLayers.js` file, provided by plugin authors (which had 'Release 2.11' version in his body and was placed at `~/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/weblayers/html` folder in my system) to last 2.13.1 version from official [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/two/) site (pay attention, 2.+ version!).

Just download the archive, extract to temporary folder and copy `OpenLayers.js` (750+ Kb) to where the same file exists in QGIS plugin folder (I think it will be `C:\Users\<UserName>\.qgis2\python\plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\html\` in Windows system).

In my case problem was solved.

Comment: This hasn't helped the situation for me, in fact it made the offset greater.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a different workaround than you are thinking, but when I have had issues with the Google Maps plugin I reprojected my data into EPSG:3857 and then did all my work there, then I reprojected it back to the original projection once I finished.

I've also realised when working with the plugin that sometimes the projection renders a little wonky and I just have to move the map around or scroll in or out and then my data matches up again.

Answer (score 2):

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42141/8210

> The problems with the Openlayers plugin and the print composer last for years now, without a solution. As a consequence, try to avoid the Openlayers plugin when you need a print output. A new plugin, QuickMapServices, has been developed in the meantime. I suggest to try that.

Using the QuickMapServices plugin has worked for me, and just as easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reproject Google Maps data. I know I never could.

Just reproject your own vector layer to the coordinate system Google Maps uses.

Comment: As @herb said, the Google Map tiles use a projection of EPSG:3857.