# QGIS OpenLayers plugin needs to be reloaded

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

Using QGIS 2.12, I successfully add basemaps via Web > OpenLayers plugin.

However, if I save the project (EPSG:3857) and later reopen it, the OpenLayers basemap will not display.  As a workaround, if I delete the "blank" basemap from the table of contents and then add it again via Web > OpenLayers, the basemap will display correctly.  However, this must be redone every time I reopen the project.

This problem is not a show-stopper, but it is aggravating.  Has anyone else experienced this oddity?

Comment: Do you have to remove and re-add the basemap or is it sufficient to pan the map slightly? For me this works.

Comment: You are correct; panning or zooming will help.  However, please see the answer below from romainbh.  The QMS plugin is a big improvement over the OpenLayers plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of OpenLayers, you ca use QuickMapServices. All maps added in a project remain when the project is reopened, and QMS is more stable as OL.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion doesn't work for me because QMS does not offer Google or Bing basemaps.  I probably should  have mentioned Google and Bing in my original post.

Comment: Quick Map Services supports Bing and Google if you go to settings --> Contributed Services --> get contribution pack

Comment: Fantastic!  QMS is great.  Additionally, image tiles load more reliably (fewer missed tiles on refresh) and you're not stuck with just EPSG:3857 as a coordinate reference system.  Thanks!