# Vector and OpenLayers rendering problem

Tags: qgis, polygon, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm pretty new to QGIS (2.14.3) and am half way between singing its praises and hitting my head against the desk. I've been having a particularly vexing problem recently with a map I've created.

In the image (Fig 1) below you will see that I'm mapping out rivers and riparian areas. I'm projecting into WGS84/Pseudo Mercator.

(1) What I can't understand is that it appears like the OpenLayers image in the background has shifted when the jpg file is being made. In fact if you look closely, neither the full map nor the overview map is in the correct (or even the SAME) position. However, in the print composer (Fig 2) the image and layers line up perfectly.

(2) The buffer I've created (yellow and red line) should look like it does in the overview map however if you look in the full map where I've zoomed into a particular section, you'll see that it suddenly cuts across from north-west to south-east on the right-hand side of the map. Nothing I do has corrected this, including remaking the layers. This problem seems to persist in print composer, QGIS and the jpeg files. [Edit] There is also mean to be a bridge displayed in red but that doesn't seem to show in the print composer or JPEG either.

Fig 1: Jpeg file
[image]

Fig 2: Print composer view
[image]

Am I missing something? Or is this just a freak event? I'm very close to just taking a screenshot of the Print Composer and using that at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Problems with OpenLayers in the print composer have been well documented for years now (for example, see [Why do OpenLayers plugin layers appear shifted in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/why-do-openlayers-plugin-layers-appear-shifted-in-qgis-print-composer)). Use QuickMapServices instead.

Comment: Thanks @tirefire , any ideas about the changing buffer layer?

Comment: If removing OpenLayers didn't solve it, I couldn't say for sure. Generally problems like this are due to a projection issue. I would start troubleshooting by double-checking to make sure all my layers are indeed using the same CRS and turning off on-the-fly projection.

Answer (score 0):

Google imagery especially has problems in higher zoom levels, even outside the print composer. I'm not sure if this is only related to the openlayers plugin.

You might try the Vector Bender plugin to move the features to the right location once you changed to QMS. You need to activate the `Get Contributed Pack`to get Google Imagery in QMS settings, `More services` tab.