# QGIS print composer to image export don't match

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, export, print-composer

In QGIS I have set up a map in print composer but when I export to image or pdf the saved image does not match what is in the print composer.

Details - I am using an openstreetmap as my background map and I have a group of around 360 points witch I have uploaded from a cvs file. On the print composer the points are on one side of a river and after export they are on the other (6-7 km difference)

Any suggestions would be helpful. It seem to be working fine earlier this week.

Map as seen in print composer:
[image]

Map when exported:
[image]

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/why-do-openlayers-plugin-layers-appear-shifted-in-qgis-print-composer/142947#142947

Comment: Are you using the openlayers plugin for the OSM basemap?

Answer (score 0):

You should to reduce "Export resolution".
Web services have a limit of resolution.
Try 120 dpi, pe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately thus hasn't worked. It seems to be a problem with the location of the points rather than with resolution

Comment: Sure? try in print composer "Export resolution" = 96 dpi