# Partial loss of image when exporting from composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I Have a map in composer this is what I see

[image]

but when I export as an image or PDF this is what I get

[image]

Wondering why a small part of the image is missing on the left side of the page and how I can correct this?

Comment: Do you have the OpenLayers plugin installed?

Comment: Try refreshing the map view in QGIS desktop.
If it still persists, maybe this related to your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/openlayers-low-resolution-and-or-shifts-in-qgis-print-composer

Comment: I tried refreshing that map view and had no luck. I also looked at the link but that does not sound related.