# Adjust font size in QGIS Open Layers Plugin

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a problem with the export of open layers maps via the printcomposer. In the printcomposer window the font size of the map labels is easy readable, but if I export the map as pdf or jpg the label size decreases so that they are not readable any more. Decreasing the export resolution leads to a bigger font size in the export file, but also to a very poor quality of the pdf or jpg.
What I need is a high resolution export with a readable font size.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The plugin uses the tiles designed for screen display. There is no way of changing the font size. You may need to self-render the basemap using OpenStreetMap or other open data.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/openlayers-low-resolution-and-or-shifts-in-qgis-print-composer

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, that you use the [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) Plugin which provides the same functionality but does not have any problem regarding the shift of the map (which can be another downside of the OpenLayers Plugin).

You can install it via the  Plugin manager of QGIS. A quick intoduction to the service can be found on [their project site.](https://qms.nextgis.com/about)

Comment: This does **not**  solve the described problem. QMS can not change the font size.