# Shapefile is shifted after exporting

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-maps

[image]

I used Google Maps as a basemap. In Map Composer window it is showing in the 
correct location in QGIS, but when I try to export it, it is shifted.

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers Plugin?

Comment: yes, I used openlayers plugin to display google physical basemap.

Comment: This is a well known issue with openlayers.

Comment: Thanks.Is there any other way to do this? Quickmapservice plugin doesn't allow to display google base map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with OpenLayers to use Google map, then you need to accept the shift issue casued by openlayers, which is a well-known issue in map composer: [OpenLayers low resolution and/or shifts in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/openlayers-low-resolution-and-or-shifts-in-qgis-print-composer).

Alternatively, you can use [QuickMapService](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) (QMS) Plugin and use it to search for Google maps, and you will find many basemaps:

[image]

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Also you can use ESRI World Topo. It has everything you want in one map including shaded relief, river, and other detailed information. Type ESRI World Topo in QMS and you will find it.

[image]

Here is the output map:

[image]

Comment: When you add the contributed pack in the settings of QuickMap services you get Google Maps (normal), Hybrid, Terrain, Roads, Traffic and Satellite.

Comment: @Matte Thank you very much for your input. I didn't know that. I will update my answer.