# Where is the OpenLayers Plugin in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, basemap

I want to do a really simple thing: add OpenLayers/Google Maps basemap as WMS layers. I found this answer: [How to add Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/how-to-add-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)

I installed the OpenLayers plugin, restarted QGIS, but under "Plugins" dropdown there is no OpenLayers plugin. Is it a bug? Or I need to do also some other things to add plugin? Or where else I can find this plugin settings?

Probably my question is: how to add world basemap layer to QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS 2.4, the OpenLayers Plugin has been moved to the Web menu instead of the Plugins pull-down menu.

But if you've just upgraded from an earlier version of QGIS, be sure to upgrade OpenLayers Plugin as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the plugin in this path, else restart QGIS and reinstall plugin.

[image: OpenLayersPlugin]

Comment: That was true up to QGIS 2.2