# Convert PNG to GeoTIFF: Invalid pixelsize in geotransform array in FME

Tags: fme-form, mapbox, image

I'm converting PNG file to GeoTIFF. Here's the setup that I use in FME:

```
PNGRaster -> 
    RasterExtractor -> 
        CoordinateSystemSetter -> 
            RasterGeoReferencer -> 
                writer
```

The settings of RasterGeoReferencer:

[image]

But when I try to upload the map to mapbox I get an error: Invalid pixelsize in geotransform array. What is wrong?

Comment: Is the screenshot showing the coordinates you fill in? 'caus `1` and `2` are not the "best" coordinates ;-) ...

Comment: well it shouldn't matter, right? I used coordinates that describe range from 0,0 to 10,10 but still had the same error

Comment: For me it looks like that that tool doesn't use the coordinates from the PNG but the one you enter manually?! Did you try to open the PNG as well as the converted GeoTIFF in a GIS software (eg. QGIS) to see if it is correct georeferenced?

Comment: I can open output with QGIS, I also tried exporting geoTIFF from QGIS and got a new error: Error: bounds south value must be between -95 and 95

Comment: And the outputs in QGIS has the right position? [Add some basemaps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/how-to-add-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis) to check that. My guess, it is a matter of the projection/coordinates system. Make sure that you GeoTIFF output has the right one for the mapbox,

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way to convert raster image to a geoTIFF with WGS 84 / Preudo Mercator coordinate system using QGIS instead of FME?

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the RasterExtractor for? I don't see the point of it (although it won't be doing anything that would affect your output here)

Comment: Are you sure you have those coordinates the right way around? i.e. you have upper-left = 1,1; lower-left = 1,2 (seems to me that should be lower-left=1,1; upper-left=1,2) I'm not convinced I'm reading that right, or that it would cause a problem even so, but it just looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer really your question but I can tell you how to convert a georeferenced PNG to a GeoTIFF using QGIS.

---

#### Method 1:

1. add the raster layer to QGIS `Layer -> Add Raster Layer...`
2. right click on the feature and click on `Save as...` [image: save as]
3. chose the filename and selected the correct Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS, eg. EPSG:4326) and click okay. [image: save raster alyer]

---

#### Method 2:

Another option is the [Translate tool](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html): `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate (Convert format)`

[image: qgis translate]