# Open Street Map Base Map on QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qgis-android

I am using QField on an Android tablet, I would like to know if I could use a web mapping service like open street map as a base map. Without having the actual file stored on the tablet?

Answer (score 2):

QField supports many map sources as backend, file, database and **web-based like WMS and WMTS**.

Among these supported formats is the *Tile Server (XYZ) provider*. This can be used to integrate maps like OSM and others. See [this answer for how to integrate this into your QGIS project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217670/9839).

[image]

Comment: Hello Matthias Kuhn ... is the answer above still the appropriate method for including XYZ tile access in QField? I have ebcountered problems with my projects leveraging this capacity that had been working well in the past. Have further detailed some of the issue here: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265820/how-to-get-xyz-tiles-to-work-in-qfield

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Web Map Service set up in your QGIS project which is then packaged up with 'QField_Sync' plugin.

Comment: but this method doesn't give the best result in qfield. it gives an error wich says "some layers couldn't be loaded"  or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [QuickMapsServices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) fort QGIS? This plugin provide more than 500 base maps (OpenStreetMap too).

The [QMS](https://qms.nextgis.com/) service also integrated with [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/) (a QField alternative). See documentation about how to add base map: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngmobile/source/load_geodata.html#creating-raster-layer-from-external-geoservice

[image]