# QGIS displays orthophoto distorted

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, orthophoto

See photos. Both are screenshots of the same geotiff (orthophoto) image. Standard Windows (and other viewers) display the image correctly. QGIS shows the same image distorted.

The image is from Agisoft Photoscan. Orthophoto and QGIS Projection is "WGS 84 (EPSG::4326)".

When measuring an rectangual object in the orthophoto I got 105 degrees instead 90 degrees in one corner.

What's wrong/missing?

[image][image]

---

Comment: What projection is the orthophoto in? Is it being displayed in a different projection? That is a common cause of distortion.

Comment: Maybe try EPSG 25832 or 25833 as projection (assuming you're working within Germany/Austria based on your QGIS language). If something is distorted, you can also use OSM as a background to check for correct placement and projection.

Comment: Agisoft PhotoScan orthophoto? Isn't the first time seeing this issue in this site

Comment: QGIS is not like standard viewers because it is aware or coordinate systems. Your project seems to be in EPSG:4326 and QGIS warps the image on-the-fly to suit with EPSG:4326.

Comment: Can you add a basemap behind the image? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670

Answer (score 2):

solved: image was not made with EPSG:4326; correct coordinate system EPSG:31466 used and everything is OK now.