# Why does QGIS image sometimes appear on an angle?

Tags: qgis

Why does the satellite imagery that I bring in and the KMZ file appear to be on an angle, as if it's angled back rather than being a top down view?

Here's a screenshot that should better explain what I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: Ok, figured it out :-) Had to change the projection settings. Project > PRoject Properties > Proper UTM Zone!

Comment: I think you should expand your answer into about a short paragraph and make it an answer.

Comment: Similar question was asked yesterday https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286194/qgis-displays-orthophoto-distorted and many times before.

Comment: Yes, but it's not an easy question to look up and find... or at least when I used my search terms I could not find the solution. Seems counterintuitive to remove a question with a solution when others may find it useful.