# Openlayers in QGIS - Errors in opening google satellite/

Tags: qgis, dem, google-earth, contour, qgis-openlayers-plugin

End goal: To put contour lines with lat&long layers from a google earth location (Rock Piles beach, HI) in QGIS. I plan to use CRS: EPSG:3760

Does the Plug in (Openlayers / QuickMapServices) already have the D.E.M (xyz file) or do I need to get it from somewhere else?

I installed both 'openlayers plugin' and 'quickmapservers' plugins in QGIS. Then when I go to the web tab > openlayer plugin > Google Maps > Google physical.
This message shows:

[image]

The google terrain still downloads, but when I double-click the layer to see the properties, this message pops out:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Which QGIS are you using?

Comment: I think those are just the limitations of the plugin - there are ways to use the Tile XYZ with those same services that overcome these issues

Comment: QGIS 2.18 (Las palmas) @aldo_tapia

Comment: oh okay I see and how would I be able to do that. You can show me a link or doc to read.  @DPSSpatial

Comment: Maybe you aren't working with OTF (on the fly projection). You can try with QGIS 3.0 for this purpose, those plugins work really great and you can add custom XYZ tiles very easily

Comment: @UliDiaz try this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217670/9880

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it at the end because I had several problems with version 3.0 on my laptop (SurfacePro 4) so I down graded to 2.18 and haven't had as many problems @aldo_tapia

Comment: thank you! I'll look into it let you know if it worked. @DPSSpatial