# Error when activating plugins in QGIS 3 on MacOS X?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, mac, quickmapservices

I'm a user of QGis, but this is the first time that I have it installed in a MAC (Sierra 10.12.6). I just installed the new version and I'm trying to install the plugins I usually use. OpenStreetMap gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'openlayers_plugin' due to an error when calling 
its classFactory() method
```

I've read that we should move to QuickMapServices, but when I activate that plugin, I have the same error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'quick_map_services' due to an error when calling
its classFactory() method 

TypeError: 'QVariant' object is not subscriptable  Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/pytho/qgis/utils.py",
line 337, in startPlugin 
  plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)   
File "/Users/delati01/Library/Application
Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/quick_map_services/__init__.py",
line 35, in classFactory 
  return QuickMapServices(iface)   File "/Users/delati01/Library/Application
Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/quick_map_services/quick_map_services.py",
line 72, in __init__
  self.locale = Locale.get_locale()   File "/Users/delati01/Library/Application
Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/quick_map_services/plugin_locale.py",
line 30, in get_locale
  return QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2] TypeError: 'QVariant' object is not subscriptable


Python version: 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54) [GCC
4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]  QGIS version: 3.2.0-Bonn Bonn, exported 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/delati01/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/delati01/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/delati01/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Is this a general error because QGIS has just been updated or is it from MacOS X?

Comment: There are many plugins for QGIS on all platforms that haven't been updated for QGIS 3 yet (openlayers is still 'experimental' for v3 at this time) ... in the meantime, you could either stick with 2.18 until the final version 3 is out, or add basemaps via methods like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading that post, that's how I found out about QuickMapServices, but the basemaps don't load anything. The screen is always white...

Comment: there are a lot of services in the QuickMapServices plugin that have sources that may or may not be maintained, but I can see the basica OSM Standard service works through QuickMapServices

Comment: Same for Windows, QGIS3 and QuickMapServices :-(