# Obtaining Free High Resolution Satellite Imagery to use in QGIS

Tags: raster, mac, imagery, satellite

I just downloaded QGIS 3.10 Mac version the other day and I am still very green with the program.  I was wondering what is the best way to obtain high resolution satellite imagery?  I know there are some websites you can pay for it, but I was wondering if there are any ways you can get it for free?

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on where you are trying to get data for.  If you're in the US then check out [The National Map](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/national-geospatial-program/national-map) - there's tons of data for all over the US listed there.

Otherwise you can look for QGIS plugins that will load basemaps and base-imagery into your QGIS project.  As described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis).

If you're outside the US, or your area of interest is, there could very well be other sources similar to this that can help you out but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Yes, in the US.  I will look into your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: The XYZ tile server in particular is a very nice feature. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217670/8104

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes your local government will provide satellite imagery of the area on an official website. Search terms to use when looking for this would be *satellite*, *imagery*, *gis*, *raster*, *download*, *[jurisdiction] data portal*, *orthophoto* and *orthoimagery*. Good luck!