# Basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, basemap

I have some problems with QGIS base maps like Google Satellite. After inserting them they just disappearing. I can see them only when I drag my map, or when I turn them on or off they just appears for one second and goes away again.

Any suggestion? (I already updated my QGIS, I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin several times, I controlled the tick box in my installed plugin, and using Windows 10)

Comment: What plugin are you using for the base maps?

Comment: I suggest you try [this approach](http://students.eagle-science.org/python-script-for-qgis-3-0-basemaps/)

Comment: I'm using QuickMapServices plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use the basemaps from the XYZ tiles in QGIS 3.x, installing them with the script by Klas Karlsson: https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/972757121933733889?lang=de

Open `Menu Plugins / Python console`, then paste [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py). In your Browser panel, you can now expand the XYZ tiles. The base maps appearing there can be added to the layer panel by drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: For more details check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/356668/99589