# Is there a Google Earth free WMS service?

Tags: qgis, google-earth, basemap, xyz-tiles

Is there a Google Earth free WMS service? Can we add the QGIS WMS service and see the current satellite images?

Comment: There's a Google Satellite *Tile Server* in my "XYZ Tiles" dropdown in my QGIS browser. Its not a WMS, but is that good enough for you? I think its the imagery used for google maps rather than whatever google earth uses...

Comment: openstreetmap is not enough, I need to get updated satellite images under vector data.

Comment: What do you mean "under vector data" - satellite images are raster data, not vector. What do you mean "updated"? How recent? Daily? Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Why did you say "openstreetmap"? Was there a deleted comment? I didn't say it.

Comment: I need to see the WMS service as a raster image under the vector layers. In QGis, only openstreetmap comes in XYZ tiles. My goal is to find a constantly updated satellite imaging service.

Comment: Use the plugin [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/)

Comment: This should do it, there are several variations of Google Maps you can add, let me know if you don't find the one you need... remember you can't use it to 'trace features', though!!  [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)

Comment: I didn't remember plugin name in my answer but @gene put it in his comment. I installed it and now, I cannot find any Google Maps services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there is a plugin available but I lost it (I don't remember the name) in one of my updates of QGIS (I have to recover it). However, you can run a following little script in Python Console to do that.

```
import requests
service_url = "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url="+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Sat", "wms")
```

First, I loaded your named "under vector data" (in my case one of my vector layers). It looks as follows:

[image]

Afterward, I opened my Python Console and I copy/paste above code for getting result of following image with "one of current satellite images". I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This code is sufficient.

Comment: You're welcome. I appreciate that you mark as accepted this answer.

Comment: I am using the same google's satellite base map and the latest revision of mosaic is from 2009 January 1st is there a newer version.

Comment: For this reason I put "one of current satellite images" in my answer (between quotation marks). Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can we do the same in Arcgis?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Arcgis.