# Seeking Web/Mac application for editing and display of gpx files

Tags: software-recommendations, mac, gpx, gps-track-editor

Recently I made month-long cycling trip through Europe. I have some gpx files of existing routes (like Eurovelo) which I used for planning. I also have ~30 gpx files of daily recordings of my route which I downloaded from Sportstracker.

I would like to organize those tracks (to e.g. remove unnecessary pieces, manually add routes where my gps was not working, merge them, etc.) and then add to map, so that I can explore (and screenshot) the maps of planned/actual route in various zooms, details, etc.

I started with https://mymaps.google.com/ which I have used before, but it has some limitations:

- only allows some number of gpx layers (like 10 or so)
- does not allow route editing
- does not load my gpx files from Sportstracker (they look like valid xml to me)

None of the apps/webs I have found seem to do what I need (e.g. no editing, or just single file, etc).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm regularly using [Viking GPX data editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/) for this (available for Windows, Mac and Linux).

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM, it does not seem to provide Mac binaries (and I only found non-trivial instructions to compile it, e.g. no homebrew), so I will try to get hold of Win machine to try it.

Comment: You are right, I just trusted info on home page that it's available also for Mac. I checked now and there is no compiled code for Mac, only for Windows and Linux. Simplest solution would be to run Windows VM on Mac.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why not use [QGIS](https://qgis.org)? QGIS offers all one needs to work with geodata and is available for Windows, macOS, Linux, BSD, Android and IOS.

Comment: @geom Thanks, QGIS seems to be able to do it. Not fastest with my 30 days of data, but usable. I need to figure out how to have it render OSM nicely.

Comment: Setting EPSG3857 fixed the rendering

Comment: @geom If you want to write answer with QGIS I am happy to accept it. If not, I will write some answer myself, explaining some details of how to do it (as general gis QGIS is not very obvious for newcomers) and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [QGIS](https://qgis.org/) (as suggested by the comments) which turned out to be a perfect solution (though it has a bit of learning curve). Here are some hints:

1. Adding base-map from major providers is easy - described e.g. in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis) If the bitmap is distorted, make sure to set the project's Coordinate Reference System (in bottom right corner) to *EPSG:3857* which seems to be standard for all online map services
2. Adding gpx files to map is basically drag&drop (various tutorials online, e.g. [this video](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)). By default, it will show both the tracks and track_points - hide the track_points to get just the solid line.
3. In Layer Properties / Symbology you can change how lines are rendered. When applying some style this seems to just copy values, so if the style is changed later, it does not update the properties. But you can edit multiple in bulk.
4. There is *Import Photos plugin* which makes it relatively easy to put entire directories of geo-tagged photos on the map as icons.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), follow the installation instructions and will find at least a large set of packages you can use on the Mac like with FreeBSD or Linux.

If you get this hurdle, you could re-use FreeBDS or Linux like related solutions as posted for *"[Scraping GPX files out of RunKeeper into Postgres and QGIS](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/scraping-gpx-files-out-of-runkeeper-into-postgres-and-qgis/)"* (which sound for me very similar to your problem in common) and find a appropriate solution, to store online data in a standardize way, explore and review them.

- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) - Is a relational Database with GIS capabilities (using [POSTGIS](https://postgis.net/)) and you can find have tools to import [GPX data](https://github.com/Zverik/gpx2pgsql).
- [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) is a Geo information system which gives you the opportunity to explore and manipulate spatial data .