# Tiles XYZ plugin for newer versions of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, tiles, xyz

I was wondering if anyone knows what replaced Tiles XYZ for newer versions of QGIS, as I cannot find it when I search for plugins and when I try and install it via zip file it says it only works with older versions of QGIS.

Comment: Are you looking for XYZ Tiles in the browser panel? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217670/276

Comment: No I am looking for the plugin used in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AZ9gPAhL_4

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out. The plugin is now already within the QGIS processing tool box and it is known as Generate XYZ Tiles (MbTiles)