# QGIS has suddenly stopped displaying Google Open Map Layers

Tags: qgis

QGIS has suddenly stopped displaying Google Open Map Layers without any apparent reason. I've tried using both the 3.22 and 3.28 versions, but none of them seem to work. This happens in new projects too. Anyone happen to have any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you access Google Maps in your QGIS? via a PLugin, XYZ  Tiles, or something else?

Comment: I access via XYZ Tiles

Comment: Try to set up the connection according to the parameters demonstrated in this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/356668/99589