# Use QGIS to visualize OpenStreetMap data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have a osm map for a certain region. Also using osm2po I extracted the graph which includes edges and nodes into the database. Now I want to visualize the map and then visualize the shortest path. How can I visualize the map in QGIS first? I mean it doesn't directly take the osm file? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: An older GIS-SE Question might be helpful - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/how-to-add-osm-layer-to-qgis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the **OpenStreetMap** Python plugin that ships with QGIS.

Choose the *Plugins-> Manage Plugins...* menu and enable the plugin.

[image]

Next, read the new HTML manual on using the plugin:
[OpenStreetMap Plugin — QGIS User Guide](http://qgis-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/plugins_openstreetmap.html)

When you are ready to start doing some path routing check out [underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark)'s info on the subject:

Tagged posts: [osm2po | Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings](http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/osm2po/)

Starting with: [An osm2po Quickstart](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/)