# Is there a way to download more than 13MB of OSM data to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, download

I'm using QGIS to make maps with OSM streetmaps data. Problem is that with QGIS -> Vector -> OSM -> download data, after about 13MB I get "Download error Operation cancelled". Sometimes I get "Download successful" after 8MB but can't import the .osm because of "XML error, Premature end of document". I reduced the areas of the download to keep the size down and two out of five were incomplete files. With Maperitive I've downloaded bigger files, from rambler.ru.  Is there some setting in QGIS to change the source of the data? Or some other way of solving the problem?

Comment: It's a limit set on the osm servers. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/how-to-add-osm-layer-to-qgis

Comment: You are better off downloading the country you are interested in shapefiles etc can be downloaded from http://downloads.cloudmade.com/ or http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html is more up to date

Answer (score 4):

Funny enough, I have been running into the same issue tonight and fixed it in this [commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d7c29ae32b48b260dfb4cb60ffcb4b0818f191da)

## Reason

The problem is not related to the server or size, but happens due to a network timeout which by default does not take into account, that data is actually being transferred. The above-mentioned commit solves this, so it should be soon in any nightly/master build.

## Workaround

Go to *Settings=>Options=>Network* and increase the *Timeout for network requests (ms)* to be large enough to transfer all the data.

Comment: That works sometimes. Increasing the timeout to 5 minutes I got 48MB intact. Next 2 downloads I got one "cancelled" at 24MB, then one "successful" (at 15MB) which was incomplete.