# How to open OSM as WMS/WMTS layer in QGIS so that it looks the same as openstreetmap.org?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I can follow [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273381/191643) to load a WMS layer to QGIS. I do: `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add WMS/WMTS Layer`. Then `Connect`, and `Add`:

[image]

I get this map:

[image]

to try how it is, I zoom in to Tromsø, as an example:

[image]

compare with [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/69.6668/18.9782):

[image]

Mine is rather distorted. This distortion is even more prominent if I zoom in to see individual buildings, and all of them lack right angles:

[image]

On the bottom left corner, I have:

[image]

If I click on it, and try to change it to EPSG:3857:

[image]

I get:

[image]

and the buildings are still distorted.

**How can I tell QGIS Desktop to open the WMS layer so that the map looks the same as it looks on [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)?**

---

EDIT 1:

If I select EPSG:3857 when adding the WMS layer:

[image]

I get:

[image]

---

EDIT 2:

If I tried to add `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` as an XYZ layer, suggested by [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423543/191643), I get part of the world map:

[image]

but somehow the southern hemisphere and part of the northern one is missing, and the coordiantes are wrong: somehow QGIS thinks that `(0,0)` coord is somewhere between Jan Mayen and Mainland Norway. See the location of my cursor and the coordinate displayed on the bottom.

Comment: Select EPSG:3857 already when you add the layer from WMS.

Comment: Thank you! I tried, see the Edit part to see what I got.

Comment: Set your QGIS project to EPSG:3857 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The openstreetmap.org loads the tiles based on an XYZ format tile url, which follows this pattern

```
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

eg. https://tile.openstreetmap.org/15/23367/14571.png
This is what appears on inspecting the openstreetmap.org website.

[image]

Try loading these as XYZ tiles in QGIS instead of WMS or WMTS.

[image]

**Edit:1** 
It should appear like as shown in the screenshot below with origin near the cyan circle

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, +1, it almost works. Unfortunately, it does not; I edited my post to explain what's wrong when I follow this path.

Comment: Set the CRS to EPSG:4326 again and check as I see your CRS is set to 3857 right now. I have updated  my response with screenshot of how it should look like when zoomed out. In case you are not getting the same output, create a new project in QGIS and add the layer again or may be try to re-install QGIS

Comment: Tried to make this work, unfortunately I still couldn't, more details are [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423682/why-do-i-see-only-about-half-of-the-world-with-mismatched-coordinates-when-addin).

Comment: I could make this work on a GCP VM, so problem is only with my computer, thanks for the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or just install QuickMapServices plugin and use several backgrounds without scratching your head :).