# Why do I see only about half of the world with mismatched coordinates when adding OSM to QGIS as an XYZ layer?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

When opening QGIS, I already have a few XYZ layers added. Full window:

[image]

If I click `Layers` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add XYZ Layer...`, then select `OpenStreetMap`, then `Edit`, I get:

[image]

which seems to be all right, and in accordance with [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423543/191643).

When I click on OpenStreetMap on the left, I get this map:

[image]

As you can see, only about half of the world is shown. The 0,0 coordinate is somewhere between Greenland and Norway (my cursor is close to this point on the screenshot, coordinate of cursor is displayed on the bottom). The warning on the top:

[image]

If I click Details, I get:

[image]

Interestingly, if I add OSM as a new XYZ layer and not use the already added one, I get an empty map.

The same thing (only half of the world is visible) happens if before opening the OpenStreetMap layer, I click on the EPSG specification on the bottom right, then find  `EPSG:3857` in the openining window and `Apply` it.

I try to uninstall QGIS through Ubuntu software:

[image]

I get this error message when I click `Remove`:

[image]

Following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278194/191643), I do:

```
sudo apt remove *qgis*
sudo apt purge *qgis*
```

then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis
```

but then I get the error (full output of second line from above):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  default-libmysqlclient-dev grass-doc gyp icu-devtools libarmadillo-dev libarpack2-dev libblas-dev libboost-dev libboost1.71-dev libc-ares2 libcfitsio-dev libcfitsio-doc
  libcharls-dev libdap-dev libdapserver7v5 libdeflate-dev libepsilon-dev libfprint-2-tod1 libfreexl-dev libfyba-dev libgeos-dev libgif-dev libheif-dev libicu-dev libjbig-dev
  libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray libjs-psl libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libjson-c-dev libkml-dev libkmlconvenience1 libkmlregionator1 libkmlxsd1 liblapack-dev liblzma-dev
  libminizip-dev libmysqlclient-dev libogdi-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpng-dev libpng-tools libpoppler-dev
  libpoppler-private-dev libpq-dev libqgis-native3.20.3 libqgis-native3.22.0 libqgis-native3.22.1 libqhull-dev libqhull-r7 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libsuperlu-dev
  libtiff-dev libtiffxx5 liburiparser-dev libuv1-dev libwebp-dev libxerces-c-dev libxml2-dev libzstd-dev node-abbrev node-ajv node-ansi node-ansi-align node-ansi-regex
  node-ansi-styles node-ansistyles node-aproba node-archy node-are-we-there-yet node-asap node-asn1 node-assert-plus node-asynckit node-aws-sign2 node-aws4
  node-balanced-match node-bcrypt-pbkdf node-bl node-bluebird node-boxen node-brace-expansion node-builtins node-cacache node-call-limit node-camelcase node-caseless
  node-chalk node-chownr node-ci-info node-cli-boxes node-cliui node-clone node-co node-color-convert node-color-name node-colors node-columnify node-combined-stream
  node-concat-map node-concat-stream node-config-chain node-configstore node-console-control-strings node-copy-concurrently node-core-util-is node-cross-spawn
  node-crypto-random-string node-cyclist node-dashdash node-debug node-decamelize node-decompress-response node-deep-extend node-defaults node-define-properties
  node-delayed-stream node-delegates node-detect-indent node-detect-newline node-dot-prop node-duplexer3 node-duplexify node-ecc-jsbn node-editor node-encoding
  node-end-of-stream node-err-code node-errno node-es6-promise node-escape-string-regexp node-execa node-extend node-extsprintf node-fast-deep-equal node-find-up
  node-flush-write-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-from2 node-fs-vacuum node-fs-write-stream-atomic node-fs.realpath node-function-bind node-gauge node-genfun
  node-get-caller-file node-get-stream node-getpass node-glob node-got node-graceful-fs node-har-schema node-har-validator node-has-flag node-has-symbol-support-x
  node-has-to-string-tag-x node-has-unicode node-hosted-git-info node-http-signature node-iconv-lite node-iferr node-import-lazy node-imurmurhash node-inflight node-inherits
  node-ini node-invert-kv node-ip node-ip-regex node-is-npm node-is-obj node-is-object node-is-path-inside node-is-plain-obj node-is-retry-allowed node-is-stream
  node-is-typedarray node-isarray node-isexe node-isstream node-isurl node-jsbn node-json-parse-better-errors node-json-schema node-json-schema-traverse
  node-json-stable-stringify node-json-stringify-safe node-jsonify node-jsonparse node-jsonstream node-jsprim node-latest-version node-lazy-property node-lcid node-libnpx
  node-locate-path node-lockfile node-lodash node-lodash-packages node-lowercase-keys node-lru-cache node-make-dir node-mem node-mime node-mime-types node-mimic-fn
  node-mimic-response node-minimatch node-minimist node-mississippi node-mkdirp node-move-concurrently node-ms node-mute-stream node-nopt node-normalize-package-data
  node-npm-bundled node-npm-package-arg node-npm-run-path node-npmlog node-number-is-nan node-oauth-sign node-object-assign node-once node-opener node-os-locale
  node-os-tmpdir node-osenv node-p-cancelable node-p-finally node-p-is-promise node-p-limit node-p-locate node-p-timeout node-package-json node-parallel-transform
  node-path-exists node-path-is-absolute node-path-is-inside node-performance-now node-pify node-prepend-http node-process-nextick-args node-promise-inflight
  node-promise-retry node-promzard node-proto-list node-prr node-pseudomap node-psl node-pump node-pumpify node-punycode node-qs node-qw node-rc node-read
  node-read-package-json node-readable-stream node-registry-auth-token node-registry-url node-request node-require-directory node-require-main-filename node-resolve
  node-resolve-from node-retry node-rimraf node-run-queue node-safe-buffer node-semver node-semver-diff node-set-blocking node-sha node-shebang-command node-shebang-regex
  node-signal-exit node-slash node-slide node-sorted-object node-spdx-correct node-spdx-exceptions node-spdx-expression-parse node-spdx-license-ids node-sshpk node-ssri
  node-stream-each node-stream-iterate node-stream-shift node-strict-uri-encode node-string-decoder node-string-width node-strip-ansi node-strip-eof node-strip-json-comments
  node-supports-color node-tar node-term-size node-text-table node-through node-through2 node-timed-out node-tough-cookie node-tunnel-agent node-tweetnacl node-typedarray
  node-typedarray-to-buffer node-uid-number node-unique-filename node-unique-string node-unpipe node-uri-js node-url-parse-lax node-url-to-options node-util-deprecate
  node-uuid node-validate-npm-package-license node-validate-npm-package-name node-verror node-wcwidth.js node-which node-which-module node-wide-align node-widest-line
  node-wrap-ansi node-wrappy node-write-file-atomic node-xdg-basedir node-xtend node-y18n node-yallist node-yargs node-yargs-parser nodejs-doc qgis-plugin-grass-common
  unixodbc-dev uuid-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gdal-bin libgdal26 libgdal29 libgeotiff5 libpdal-base12 libpdal-base9 libpdal-plugin-e57 libpdal-plugin-faux libpdal-plugin-hdf libpdal-plugin-i3s libpdal-plugin-icebridge
  libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud libpdal-plugins libpdal-util12 libproj15 libproj19 libqgis-3d3.22.3 libqgis-analysis3.22.3 libqgis-app3.22.3 libqgis-core3.22.3
  libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui3.22.3 libqgis-server3.22.3 libqgispython3.22.3 librttopo1 libspatialite7 libsqlite3-mod-spatialite proj-bin python3-gdal python3-owslib
  python3-pyproj python3-qgis python3-qgis-common qgis-providers
Suggested packages:
  libgdal-grass geotiff-bin libgeotiff-epsg otb-qgis saga gpsbabel
Recommended packages:
  qgis-plugin-grass
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdal-bin libgdal26 libgdal29 libgeotiff5 libpdal-base12 libpdal-base9 libpdal-plugin-e57 libpdal-plugin-faux libpdal-plugin-hdf libpdal-plugin-i3s libpdal-plugin-icebridge
  libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud libpdal-plugins libpdal-util12 libproj15 libproj19 libqgis-3d3.22.3 libqgis-analysis3.22.3 libqgis-app3.22.3 libqgis-core3.22.3
  libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui3.22.3 libqgis-server3.22.3 libqgispython3.22.3 librttopo1 libspatialite7 libsqlite3-mod-spatialite proj-bin python-qgis python3-gdal
  python3-owslib python3-pyproj python3-qgis python3-qgis-common qgis qgis-providers
0 upgraded, 36 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 25,9 MB/100 MB of archives.
After this operation, 310 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libproj15 amd64 6.3.1-1 [925 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libproj19 amd64 7.2.1-1~focal0 [1 103 kB]
Get:3 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 librttopo1 amd64 1.1.0-1 [178 kB]
Get:4 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgdal26 amd64 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 [6 156 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgeotiff5 amd64 1.7.0-2~focal0 [70,4 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libspatialite7 amd64 5.0.0-1~focal1 [1 768 kB]
Get:7 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libpdal-base9 amd64 2.0.1+ds-1build3 [1 739 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgdal29 amd64 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 [7 183 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-gdal amd64 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 [1 026 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gdal-bin amd64 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 [511 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-util12 amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [73,4 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-base12 amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [1 926 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-e57 amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [352 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-faux amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [32,2 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-hdf amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [94,7 kB]                                                     
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-i3s amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [249 kB]                                                      
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-icebridge amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [47,4 kB]                                               
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [80,1 kB]                                            
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpdal-plugins amd64 2.2.0+ds-1~focal2 [17,3 kB]                                                        
Get:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsqlite3-mod-spatialite amd64 5.0.0-1~focal1 [1 729 kB]                                                
Get:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 proj-bin amd64 7.2.1-1~focal0 [170 kB]                                                                   
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-pyproj amd64 2.6.1+ds-2~focal2 [315 kB]                                                          
Get:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-owslib all 0.25.0-1~focal0 [123 kB]                                                              
Fetched 25,9 MB in 8s (3 105 kB/s)                                                                                                                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libproj19:amd64.
(Reading database ... 270439 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libproj19_7.2.1-1~focal0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproj19:amd64 (7.2.1-1~focal0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgeotiff5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgeotiff5_1.7.0-2~focal0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgeotiff5:amd64 (1.7.0-2~focal0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libproj15:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libproj15_6.3.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproj15:amd64 (6.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librttopo1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-librttopo1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librttopo1:amd64 (1.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libspatialite7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libspatialite7_5.0.0-1~focal1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libspatialite7:amd64 (5.0.0-1~focal1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdal26.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdal26 (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-base9.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libpdal-base9_2.0.1+ds-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-base9 (2.0.1+ds-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-core3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libqgis-core3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-core3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-analysis3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libqgis-analysis3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-analysis3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-gui3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libqgis-gui3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-gui3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-providers.
Preparing to unpack .../10-qgis-providers_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-providers (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdal29.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libgdal29_3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdal29 (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-gdal.
Preparing to unpack .../12-python3-gdal_3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-gdal (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gdal-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../13-gdal-bin_3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gdal-bin (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-util12.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libpdal-util12_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-util12 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-base12.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libpdal-base12_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-base12 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-e57.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libpdal-plugin-e57_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-e57 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-faux.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libpdal-plugin-faux_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-faux (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-hdf.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libpdal-plugin-hdf_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-hdf (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-i3s.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libpdal-plugin-i3s_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-i3s (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-icebridge.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libpdal-plugin-icebridge_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-icebridge (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpdal-plugins.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libpdal-plugins_2.2.0+ds-1~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpdal-plugins (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-3d3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libqgis-3d3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-3d3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-app3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libqgis-app3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-app3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-customwidgets.
Preparing to unpack .../25-libqgis-customwidgets_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-customwidgets (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-server3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../26-libqgis-server3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-server3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgispython3.22.3.
Preparing to unpack .../27-libqgispython3.22.3_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgispython3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libsqlite3-mod-spatialite_5.0.0-1~focal1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 (5.0.0-1~focal1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package proj-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../29-proj-bin_7.2.1-1~focal0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking proj-bin (7.2.1-1~focal0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-qgis-common.
Preparing to unpack .../30-python3-qgis-common_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-qgis-common (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pyproj.
Preparing to unpack .../31-python3-pyproj_2.6.1+ds-2~focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pyproj (2.6.1+ds-2~focal2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-owslib.
Preparing to unpack .../32-python3-owslib_0.25.0-1~focal0_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-owslib (0.25.0-1~focal0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-qgis.
Preparing to unpack .../33-python3-qgis_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-qgis (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-qgis.
Preparing to unpack .../34-python-qgis_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-qgis (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis.
Preparing to unpack .../35-qgis_1%3a3.22.3+32focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libpdal-util12 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libproj15:amd64 (6.3.1-1) ...
Setting up librttopo1:amd64 (1.1.0-1) ...
Setting up libproj19:amd64 (7.2.1-1~focal0) ...
Setting up libspatialite7:amd64 (5.0.0-1~focal1) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 (5.0.0-1~focal1) ...
Setting up proj-bin (7.2.1-1~focal0) ...
Setting up python3-pyproj (2.6.1+ds-2~focal2) ...
Setting up libgeotiff5:amd64 (1.7.0-2~focal0) ...
Setting up libgdal29 (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Setting up python3-gdal (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Setting up python3-owslib (0.25.0-1~focal0) ...
Setting up libgdal26 (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3) ...
Setting up libpdal-base9 (2.0.1+ds-1build3) ...
Setting up libpdal-base12 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up gdal-bin (3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-e57 (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-i3s (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-icebridge (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-hdf (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugin-faux (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libqgis-core3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libqgis-analysis3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libpdal-plugins (2.2.0+ds-1~focal2) ...
Setting up libqgispython3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libqgis-server3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libqgis-3d3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libqgis-gui3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up libqgis-app3.22.3 (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.22.3+32focal); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libqgis-customwidgets (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
 python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.22.3+32focal); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up python3-qgis-common (1:3.22.3+32focal) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qgis:
 python-qgis depends on python3-qgis; however:
  Package python3-qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 python3-qgis
 python-qgis
```

Main point on the bottom:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 python3-qgis
 python-qgis
```

Following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254768/191643), I tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove qgis
sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

But I still get errors, trace very similar to the one posted above.

**How can I fix the rendering of the XYZ layer?**

Comment: Can you go to "Settings -> options- > CRS -> CRS for Layers" and select Default CRS for Layers to EPSG:4326-WGS84 and check what is the result ? Also set "CRS for Projects" to  EPSG:4326-WGS84 and see what do you get. 

In case this does not work I would assume that there is some issue with proj version mismatch that is either caused by Qgis or some plugin installed as part of it.

Comment: Checked both "CRS for Layers", and "CRS for Projects", both are set to "EPSG:4326-WGS84".

Comment: Do you have another machine with a fresh installation to cross-check annd confirm that its an environment related issue ? I cannot reproduce this on Mac Big Sur 11.6 and and QGIS 3.20.3. This seems like an issue with incompatible libraries on path.

Comment: I did check on a GCP VM, and I also could not reproduce. With the purge commands above, I tried to start from fresh on my own machine, but I am unable to do so for some reason. Maybe if you could suggest a way to remove those incompatible libraries, that would help?

Comment: posted an answer related to this below

Answer (score 1):

Found a bug filed here in QGIS related to the error you are facing wrt. uninstall and reinstall.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35649

It seems like you will have to remove older versions of libproj manually
, check this comment

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35649#issuecomment-715164382

attaching the snippet for the reference here

```
# remove offending lib while keeping package dependency installed (wow, ugly): 
# the folder path may differ on your system

 rm -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15
 ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.19 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15

# and then do
sudo apt-get install qgis
```